# DDR4 SODIMM what does the V lettering mean after the speed? E.g PC4-2666V

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr

I'm normally familar with the lettering of RAM sticks but I'm a little stuck on what V means. For exampe I know 2400T is the T suffix at the end means it meets a specific JEDEC standard. A 2400T module will have the standard clock rates for a PC-2400 stick, and has a timing of 17-17-17, and a CAS latency of 14.16(ns).

And the various others like U, E, R etc but what is V for e.g it has 2666V? I intitally thought this was a Micron thing, but I have also noticed that Samsung, SK Hynix and Micron use it but have absolutely no idea what the meaning behind the V implies. Hopefully one of you bright sparks can answer this question.

The ram stick in question is below:

[image]

Please note I am not asking for recommedations of ram. I beleive in matching ram sticks and therefore I would simply buy another one of these. I'm just intrested what the V stands for as I unable to find information on this lettering and would like to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **V** suffix at the end means that it meets a specific Speed Bin in the JEDEC standard for DDR4-2666.

A **DDR4-2666V** module will have a timing of ***19-19-19***, and a CAS latency of ***14.25***(ns).

See the table from the spec sheet (from [here](https://hardforum.com/threads/jedec-standard-timings.1991642/#post-1044459069) or see *page 208* [in the spec PDF](https://www.softnology.biz/pdf/JESD79-4B.pdf#page=208))
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Each of the JEDEC module standards for [DDR4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM) have a letter at the end of their standard name, to indicate differences within that class.

Per the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_DDR4_module) DDR4 2666 has variations T, U, V, and W, where T has 17-17-17 timings, and 12.75CL, whereas W has 20-20-20 and CL of 15.

The letters seem to be assigned in sequence, from lower to higher, but there is some overlap (for instance there is a DDR4-2933W).